# Eigenvalues of the given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[image]

The normal method of finding out the determinant is taking too much time and despite that I am not getting the result.

Using an online calculator I got the eigenvalues as:

[image]

Which doesn't seem to satisfy the result!

Edit: Actual question: 
[image]

Comment: The sum can be directly computed as $tr(A^2)$ (Schur's lemma).

Comment: That still doesn't explain why the online calculator gives the wrong result?

Comment: The problem is wrong.

Comment: @AJ_ it seems that the sum is 2085 which I just calculated using Python. So the question is wrong itself.

Comment: I just double checked in matlab. The value of the eigenvalues are indeed    35.2470, 14.7530, 25.0000 which doesn't seem to satisfy the question. Where is this question from?

Comment: Sorry for all this, when I traced the actual source of the question - it seems there was a typo.

Comment: Ah no worries. :)

Comment: @AJ_ in this case the sum is easily obtained as 1925, verifying the statement.

Comment: I still don't get how to solve the question though! (without using Schur's lemma as that is not a part of our syllabus)

Comment: @AJ_ if you want to avoid Schur's lemma, an easy alternative will be Vieta's lemma, namely you compute $\det(\lambda I-A)$ and then express the (symmetric) sum in terms of $\sum \lambda_i$ and $\sum \lambda_i\lambda_j$.

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter the important parts of your question as text instead of pasting pictures of them. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. Without any of those images that you posted, your question is gibberish. Use MathJax to format the mathematical expressions. You can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).